# Is this a valid HTML disabled tag? <input .... disabled/>

Tags: html, input

i came across this HTML tag which has a disabled optional attribute "disabled", however it seem to have worked for a long time in IE6 environment, it looks like it is not declared correctly.

```
 <input name="selectBoltonButton" type="Submit" value="Select Bolt-Ons "  disabled>
```

Ideally, it should look something like this: according to w3schools:

```
 <input name="selectBoltonButton" type="Submit" value="Select Bolt-Ons "  disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: both of them should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both valid HTML, while only the latter is valid XHTML. SGML allows this, and so do its HTML children, where this is called a ["boolean attribute"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2). HTML5 [retains this concept](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes).

XHTML, on the other hand, is a dialect of XML, which [has a restriction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.5) that all attributes must have values.

Answer (score 1):

Who really cares whether it's "valid", it will have zero impact on anything.

That said, the SGML declaration [used by HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/sgmldecl.html) allows attribute minimization, whereas the [XML SGML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1.dcl) (used by XHTML) does not (`FEATURES MINIMIZE ATTRIB VALUE NO`). So take your pick.

If you're one of these modern HTML5-Web2.0 people, then none of the above will be relevant to you and you probably just write `disabled`.